# Appium iOS Android list element click

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, automated-tests, appium, codeceptjs

I use `codeceptjs` and `appium` for e2e Android + iOS.

How can I make a step for clicking 1st or other number in RecyclerView (android) or any list in iOS.
I have list id so I can locate it but I can't locate listitems with content-decsription as normal view because they are dynamic.

```
Then('I click {} element of {} list', (elementNumber, listName) => {
      I.tap(locate(listName).at(1))
})
```